# Remove occurrence from series

Tags: calendar, icalendar, vcal

I am using the RRule in http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html for recurrence.
If I modify/update one of the recurrence how can I send out new ics files with the recurrence and eg. remove that occurrence?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change one of the occurrences of your series to a different date, you

- either need to use the EXDATE property ([http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.1]) if you delete an occurrence
- or create a separate VEVENT for that date that refers the UID of the parent series via the RECURRENCE-ID ([http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.4]) in case you want to modify an occurrence.

If you want to change it after sending out and invitation, you need to identify the appointment by its UID, find a bigger SEQUENCE number ([http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.7.4]) and send it iTIP-Style with a METHOD:REQUEST